# Mulesoft: Find for a value in array and replace the contents based on 2nd array

Tags: arrays, json, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

1st Array - set of items with pricing and shipping information.
Note:

1. The same ItemID is having 2 ItemFinalPrices(ItemPrice and
   ShippingPrice).
2. All other values in 1st array should be present in the
   final message.
3. Only if ItemID is present in 2nd array their
   respective prices should be updated.

   ```
   [
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 849.98,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 10.0,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 1849.98,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 90.0,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 189.98,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 190.0,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    }
   ```

   ]

My 2nd Array is a list of ItemIds with updated Pricing and Shipping amount information.
This array will not have all the items., it will just have updated item details.

```
[
  {
    "ItemId": "1000300",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 99.98,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 19.72
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "1000549",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 199.99,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 14.12
  }
]
```

For updated items, the respective Price Info and for other Items - the old PriceInfo has to be mapped.
Expected Output:

```
 [
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300", // ItemID is present in updated array, so updated price info to be mapped
            "ItemFinalPrice": 99.98,  //Updated UpdatedItemPrice
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 19.72, //Updated UpdatedShippingAmount
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541", //Same ItemId and same price info
            "ItemFinalPrice": 1849.98,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 90.0,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549", //ItemID is present in updated array, so updated price info to be mapped
            "ItemFinalPrice": 199.99, //Updated UpdatedItemPrice
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 14.12, //Updated UpdatedShippingAmount
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using leftJoin and update :

```
%dw 2.0
import leftJoin from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json

var actuals = [
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 849.98
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000300",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 10.0
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 1849.98
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000541",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 90.0
        }
    },
    {
        "ItemPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 189.98
        },
        "ShippingPrice": {
            "ItemID": "1000549",
            "ItemFinalPrice": 190.0
        }
    }
]
var updates = [
  {
    "ItemId": "1000300",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 99.98,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 19.72
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "1000549",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 199.99,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 14.12
  }
]
---
leftJoin(actuals, updates, (actuals) -> actuals.ItemPrice.ItemID, (updates) -> updates.ItemId
) map ( $ update {
    case ip at .l.ItemPrice.ItemFinalPrice -> $.r.UpdatedItemPrice default $.l.ItemPrice.ItemFinalPrice
    case sp at .l.ShippingPrice.ItemFinalPrice -> $.r.UpdatedShippingAmount default $.l.ShippingPrice.ItemFinalPrice
}).l
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution using FirstWith() and the conditional update operator. The payload is the first array.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var updates=[
  {
    "ItemId": "1000300",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 99.98,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 19.72
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "1000549",
    "UpdatedItemPrice": 199.99,
    "UpdatedShippingAmount": 14.12
  }
]
---
payload map do {
    var thisUpdate= updates firstWith ((update, index) -> update.ItemId == $.ItemPrice.ItemID)
    ---
    $ update {
        case ItemPrice at .ItemPrice.ItemFinalPrice if (thisUpdate != null) -> thisUpdate.UpdatedItemPrice 
        case ShippingPrice at .ShippingPrice.ItemFinalPrice if (thisUpdate != null) ->  thisUpdate.UpdatedShippingAmount 
    }
}
```